# What is this red totem?

Tags: volgarr-the-viking

What is the purpose of this totem, frequently found on the first level in [Volgarr the Viking](http://store.steampowered.com/app/247240/Volgarr_the_Viking/)?

[image: totem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a static level background prop (may indicate progress). The second level uses lamppost instead of the cross:

[image: lamppost]